# Where to place the flask-migrate --multidb flag in a script?

Tags: python, database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I need to add multiple databases to a program I wrote based on a legacy version of [Miguel Grinberg's Flask Mega-Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database-legacy). I have a couple of databases configured with `SQLALCHEMY_BINDS` and they are working well, but the problem comes when I migrate them to a new version. Instead of getting three updated versions of my three databases, the three get collapsed into three tables in my first database. I understand from doing some research that this is because Alembic gets confused and munges the new versions together into the first database leaving the remaining two unaltered. I know I need to add the `--multidb` [flag](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#multiple-database-support) to solve this problem. It would typically be part of initializing:

```
$ flask db init --multidb
```

But I'm wondering where I place it in the scripts I have based on his tutorial (`config.py`, `db_create.py`, `db_migrate.py`, `downgrade.py`). My guess is perhaps somewhere in the `db_migrate.py` script? Or maybe the `__init__.py` file? Can you give me a nudge in the right direction? Thanks!

**migrate.py**

```
import imp
from migrate.versioning import api
from app import db
from config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
from config import SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO
migration = SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO + '/versions/%03d_migration.py' %(api.db_version(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO) + 1)
tmp_module = imp.new_module('old_model')
old_model = api.create_model(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
exec old_model in tmp_module.__dict__
script = api.make_update_script_for_model(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO, tmp_module.meta, db.metadata)
open(migration, "wt").write(script)
api.upgrade(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
print 'New migration saved as ' + migration
print 'Current database version: ' + str(api.db_version(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO))
```

**`__init__.py`**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO, emit
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'shhhhhh!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from app import views, models
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old version of the tutorial did not use Flask-Migrate, it uses a homegrown solution based on a different migration tool than Alembic. You can't really fit Flask-Migrate/Alembic into those scripts, they are totally incompatible.

You can look at the new version of the tutorial, specifically Chapter 4, to learn how to work with Flask-Migrate.

Comment: Thanks for your response - and thanks for your tutorials, they've been a huge resource for me! Before I go after a complete rewrite, is there a way to handle multi-database migration using the old homegrown solution?